# How can I call base class's operator==?

Tags: c++

My problem is just i dont know what to paste where i writed ***HELP_HERE***(see the code above class Dog in function bool operator==) in order to get he comparation between the type Animal of two Dogs. Each dog is an Animal so i need to be able to return the variable that represents "the animal inside the dog". In java i could just use super() and it works what do i need in c++?

`

```
#include "Animal.h"


class Dog : public Animal
   {
      private:
      char _name;
      int _age;
      int _hps;
      float _peso; // peso is Weight
public:
Dog(char name,int age, float peso, int hps) : Animal(name,age),_peso(peso),_hps(hps) {}

void roar(std::ostream &os) const {
    os << "O cao " << _name << " esta a ladrar\n.";
}
 int Vidas() const {
    return _hps;
}
float Peso() const {
    return _peso;
}
int returnAnimal() {
    return animal.Age();
}
bool operator==(const Dog &dog) {

    return HELP_HERE.operator==(dog.HELP_HERE) &&
        dog.Vidas() == _hps && dog.Peso() == _peso; 
}

friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Dog &dog) {
    dog.roar(os);
    return os;
}
};`
```

Class Animal:

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
#include <iostream>


class Animal {
   int _age;
   char _name;
public:
   Animal(int age) : _age(age),_name('-') {}
   Animal(int age, char name) : _age(age), _name(name) {}

   int Age() const { return _age; }
   char Name() const { return _name; }

   friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Animal &animal) {
       animal.sleep(os);
       return os;
   }
   void sleep(std::ostream &os) const {
      os << "the animal " << Name() << " is sleeping.\n";
   }
   void Age(int age) { _age = age; }
   bool operator==(const Animal &animal) { 
      return _age == animal.Age() && _name == animal.Name(); 
   }
};

#endif // ANIMAL_H
```

Comment: Doesn't `Animal::operator==(...)` work?

Comment: You repeat age and name in animal and dog.

Comment: what should i put in the (...) ?

Comment: I think its suposed to be like that

Comment: For easier syntax, create a virtual function named compare and have operator == in animal call the function.

Comment: It means that referring to age in dog refers to a different age than the one in animal.

Comment: You are right i can forget the age and name on class dog. But i dont know about virtual functions yet.

Comment: What happens if you have an animal pointer to a dog and an animal pointer to a cat, and you call == between them?

Answer (score 0):

Change `HELP_HERE.operator==(dog.HELP_HERE)` to:

```
Animal::operator==(dog)
```

In general you can get an Animal reference with: `Animal &a = *this;` . C++ doesn't have a keyword which indicates "the parent class", however you can always make your child class contain `typedef Animal super;` and then you can use `super::operator==`, or `super &a = *this;` etc.

Comment: ...And there are a lot of hanging extra characters... and the arguments in `Animal` are reversed comparing how the ctor is called from the derived class... and... and... and...

Comment: @SaniHuttunen yeah maybe I shouldn't have started with the general critique :)

Comment: Im a noob forgive me xD